# How to send multiple http request with different Ids at once?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to make multiple HTTP request at once using different indexes. For example below:
I have '*documentIndexes*' and I would like to pass each indexes in my *getData()* method as *indx* values to send 3 http request.

The requests will look like this:

> this.document = await firstValueFrom(this._dataService.getData(
> options.Id,
> options.rawIndex,
> indx (1)
> ));

> this.document = await firstValueFrom(this._dataService.getData(
> options.Id,
> options.rawIndex,
> indx (2)
> ));

> this.document = await firstValueFrom(this._dataService.getData(
> options.Id,
> options.rawIndex,
> indx (3)
> ));

Currently, I am using for loop, and it works fine. Is there a better way to do this? using RxJS?

```
const documentIndexes = [1,2,3]

  for (let index = 0; index < documentIndexes.length; index++) {
        const indx = documentIndexes[index];
        this.document = await firstValueFrom(this._dataService.getData(
          options.Id,
          options.rawIndex,
          indx
        ));
        this.allDoc.push(this.document)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forkJoin` to create a single observable that emits an array of all respones:

```js
const documentIndexes = [1,2,3];
const documentRequests = documentIndexes.map(
    index => this._dataService.getData(options.Id, options.rawIndex, index)
);

const documents$ = forkJoin(documentRequests);

documents$.subscribe({
    next: documents => console.log('array of documents:', documents)  
});
```

However, sometimes when you have many requests, you don't want to send them at the same time.  You can achieve the same effect, but limit the number of concurrent requests by using `mergeMap` with `reduce / scan`:

```js
const documentIndexes = [1,2,3, ... 99];

const documents$ = from(documentIndexes).pipe( // emit each index one at a time
    mergeMap(index => this._dataService.getData(options.Id, options.rawIndex, index), 5) // limit to 5 concurrent requests
    reduce((all, doc) => all.concat(doc), []) // emit an array of all results
);

documents$.subscribe({
    next: documents => console.log('array of documents:', documents)  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A pretty direct translation to RxJS:

```ts
const documentIndexes = [1,2,3]

from([...Array(3).keys()]).pipe(
  map(index => documentIndexes[index]),
  mergeMap(indx => this._dataService.getData(
    options.Id,
    options.rawIndex,
    indx
  )),
  toArray()
).subscribe(documents => this.allDoc = documents);
```

A translation with a few steps removed:

```ts
const documentIndexes = [1,2,3]

forkJoin(documentIndexes.map(
  indx => this._dataService.getData(
    options.Id,
    options.rawIndex,
    indx
  )
)).subscribe(documents => this.allDoc = documents);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't await each call. Put all the promises in an array, then use `Promise.all()`.

```js
const documentIndexes = [1, 2, 3];
let promises = documentIndexes.map(indx => firstValueFrom(this._dataService.getData(
  options.Id,
  options.rawIndex,
  indx)));
let docs = await Promise.all(promises);
this.allDoc = this.allDoc.concat(docs);
```

Answer (score 0):

`concatMap` with each id to getData, then use `toArray` get all values inside an array

```
const documentIndexes = [1,2,3];

from(documentIndexes).pipe(
  concatMap((indx) => this._dataService.getData(options.Id, options.rawIndex, indx)),
  toArray()
).subscribe(...);
```