# Angular rxjs call http requests in batches with a delay

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array of subscriptions :

```
const partsArray = parts.map(item => this.partsService.deletePart(item.id));
```

Then I call a forkJoin on subscriptions and delete them all at once :

```
  forkJoin(partsArray).subscribe({
    error: (error: ApiError) => {
      
    },
    complete: () => {
     
    }
  });
```

The problem is that it could be 10 or 100, so I need to batch them and make a delay every 10.

```
10 API CALLS 
Delay of 500ms
10 API calls 
Delay of 500ms
```

How can I make it with rxjs ?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73377839/1858357)

Comment: Yes thats the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have millions of parts, you can chunk the array ahead of time.

```ts
function chunk(arr, chunkSize) {
  if (chunkSize <= 0) throw "Invalid chunk size";
  let v = [];
  for (let i=0,len=arr.length; i<len; i+=chunkSize) {
    v.push(arr.slice(i,i+chunkSize));
  }
  return v;
}

const delayObs = timer(500).pipe(ignoreElements());

// An array of observables
const partsArray = parts.map(item => this.partsService.deletePart(item.id));

const partsChunked = chunk(partsArray, 10);

const apiResultsChunked = from(partsChunked).pipe(
  concatMap(parts => concat(forkJoin(parts), delayObs))
);

apiResultsChunked.subscribe({
  next: console.log,
  error: (error: ApiError) => {
    
  },
  complete: () => {
   
  }
});
```

---

You can simplify this a bit if you use RxJS buffer instead of pre-chunking your array.

```ts
from(
  parts.map(item => this.partsService.deletePart(item.id))
).pipe(

  bufferCount(10),
  concatMap(parts => concat(
    forkJoin(parts), 
    timer(500).pipe(ignoreElements())
  ))

).subscribe({
  next: console.log,
  error: (error: ApiError) => {},
  complete: () => {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just like this**

```
from(parts).pipe(
  map(({ id }) => this.partsService.deletePart(id)),
  bufferCount(10),
  concatMap((apis) => forkJoin(apis).pipe(delay(500)))
).subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score -2):

this may be what you are looking for.

```
const partsArray = parts.map(item => this.partsService.deletePart(item.id).pipe(delay(500)));

forkJoin(partsArray).subscribe(...)
```

check this documentation about RxJs: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/delay

Comment: SO it delays each request and I want to delay after each 10th

Comment: take a look at the other answers that use bufferCount + Delay. Read the docs for better undestanding